# Expected collisions for perfect 32bit crc

Tags: probability, crc, crc32, probability-theory

I'm trying to determine how my crc compares to an "**ideal**" 32bit crc.

So I ran my crc over 1 million completely random samples of data and collected the amount of collisions, I want to compare this number to the number of collisions I could expect from the "**ideal**" crc.

Does anyone know how to calculate the expected collision for an "**ideal**" 32bit crc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This explains beautifully the "Birthday Problem" and all about predicting the collision probability [CRC32 Hash Collision Probability](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=149670)

Answer (score 9):

Compare your own CRC with 0x1EDC6F41 as your "ideal" reference.

Having said that, there is no ideal 32-bit CRC.  Different polynomials have different collision characteristics depending on the length of data hashed.  However, a paper by Castagnoli in 1993 found what is considered the best 32-bit CRC value over the broadest range of data lengths, which is 0x1EDC6F41.  This polynomial is used by some network protocols like iSCSI and also the x86 CRC32 instruction.