# Probability of collision when using a 32-bit hash

Tags: algorithm, hash, collision, probability, crc

I have a 10-character string key field in a database. I've used CRC32 to hash this field, but I'm worrying about duplicates. Could somebody show me the probability of collision in this situation?

P.S.: My string field is unique in the database. If the number of string fields is 1 million, what is the probability of a collision?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Duplicate of [Expected collisions for perfect 32bit crc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675728/expected-collisions-for-perfect-32bit-crc)

The answer referenced this article: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=149670

Found the image below from: http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities

[image]

Comment: SO WHAT's THE ANSWER?

Comment: Technically, odds of a meteor landing on your house is 0, unless your house is in orbit.

Answer (score 47):

In the case you cite, at least one collision is essentially guaranteed.  The probability of at least one collision is about 1 - 3x10<sup>-51</sup>.  The average number of collisions you would expect is about 116.

In general, the average number of collisions in *k* samples, each a random choice among *n* possible values is:

[image: N(n,k)~=k(k-1)/(2n)]

The probability of at least one collision is:

[image: p(n,k)~=1-e^(-k(k-1)/(2n))]

In your case, *n* = 2<sup>32</sup> and *k* = 10<sup>6</sup>.

The probability of a *three*-way collision in your case is about 0.01.  See the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: Thank you so much, I wonder that this probability still depend on CRC32 algorithm ?

Comment: Any good 32-bit hash algorithm will give exactly the same result.