# Generating variations of checksum functions to minimize collisions

Tags: python, diff, md5, hash-function, adler32

My goal is to efficiently perform an exhaustive diff of a directory tree. Given a set of files `F`, I must compute the equivalence classes `EQV = [F₁, F₂, F₃, ... Fₙ]` such that `fⱼ, fₖ ∈ EQV[i] iff (fⱼ is identical to fₖ) for all i, j, k`.

My general approach is to start with just one big class containing all initial files, `EQV₀ = [[f₁, f₂, ..., fₙ]]`, and repeatedly split it into more refined classes `EQV₁`, `EQV₂`... `EQVₘ₋₁`, based on some `m` heuristics, for example, file size, checksum function 1, checksum 2. After all `m` heuristics have been applied (`EQVₘ₋₁`), a pairwise diff of all the files within each class in `EQVₘ₋₁` must be made. Because this last step is quadratic for each of the classes in `EQVₘ₋₁`, ie

```
O(sum(n² for n in map(len, EQVₘ₋₁)) )
```

and will probably be the bottleneck of my algorithm if each the m splits are done in linear time, my goal is to make `EQVₘ₋₁` as flat as possible.

I would like to have access to a variety of good hash functions that I can apply to minimize collisions on `EQVₘ₋₁`. My current idea is to use some library provided checksum function, such as adler, and to generate variations of it by simply applying it to different starting bytes within the file. Another one is to first apply fast hash functions, such as adler, and then more expensive ones such as md5 on only the classes which are still too large.

Considering that I can compute all the hashes for a given file in just one read of that file, how could I compute a variety of hashes that will help me discriminate among non-identical files?

Alternatively, what is a good list of hash functions available in python that aren't cryptographically secure?

Edit:
Another idea seems to use "rabin fingerprint" based on a fixed set of randomly generated inputs. Would this make sense for this purpose?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint

Comment: Thanks @Veedrac for your edits, now I know how to format these math symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend first using [`adler32`, then `crc32`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zlib.html).  There may be many very short files that have the same `adler32`'s, but different `crc32`'s.  In fact, you could consider a single step using `crc32` on files below a certain size on the first pass.  That size could be about 1K.  For longer files, `adler32` and `crc32` will have close to the same collision probability.

Depending on how many files you have, you could consider a subsequent step with larger hashes, such as [`md5` or `sha1`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/hashlib.html).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210298/probability-of-collision-crc32) for the probability and count of expected collisions for a 32-bit check value.  Roughly, if you have millions of files, that step may be worth doing.

You will get no benefit by going to even longer hash values.  The 128 bits from md5 is plenty to distinguish all of the files on every computer in the world.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on small files, I do notice that often some of the largest classes are those with small files. 
Since I can compute a constant number of `adler32`s of different starting bytes on the same file without incurring additional complexity,  I was thinking of computing `adler32` on the first 10 blocks of 128 bytes, for example. Are these 10 `adler32`s likely to be different if the files do differ?

Comment: Also, thanks for answering my question! It's a pleasant surprise to get an answer from the same author of this useful algorithm.

Comment: 128 bytes of input is too little for `adler32`.  You should do at least 1K blocks.  Then you will get full use of the 32 bits.

Comment: What I meant is, 10 `adler32`s starting on each of the first 128 blocks, ie as if the files had been truncated before that point. Not `adler32` on just one block of 128 bytes, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Simpler and faster would be to simply do two `adler32`s, each on half of the file.  That effectively gives you a 64-bit check instead of a 32-bit check, with a much, much lower probability of collisions for differing files.  Doing more than two independent `adler32`s would have vastly diminishing returns in this application.  As before, you should use `crc32` on files less than 1K, or less than 2K if splitting the file in two for two `crc32`'s.