# Compile-time only CRC32 user literal

Tags: c++, c++17

Can't get this to work and my brain is melting. The code looks like it should work. I want the function to only work at compile-time and not generate any runtime code or a callable function.

```
template< char... str >
constexpr uint32_t operator "" _crc( )
{
    constexpr auto lambda = [ ]( auto l,
                                 uint32_t crc,
                                 auto first,
                                 auto ... lstr )
    {
        if constexpr ( sizeof...( lstr ) == 0 )
            return ~crc;

        return l( l,
                  uCRCTable[ ( crc ^ first ) & 0xFF ] ^ crc >> 8,
                  lstr... );
    };
    return lambda( lambda,
                   uCRCTable[ 0 ],
                   str... );
}

static_assert( 0xC213271D == "stack overflow"_crc );
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `error C3688: invalid literal suffix '_crc'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""_crc' not found`

Comment: You know than you can use loop (since C++14) in constexpr.

Comment: @Jarod42 Understood. Completely forgot about it. I'll rewrite the code using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `<char...>`-overload of `operator""` is only usable for numbers, not for strings:

```
template <char ...cs>
constexpr int operator""_boom()
{
  return sizeof...(cs);
}

void test()
{
  static_assert(1234_boom == 4, "");
  static_assert("abcd"_boom == 4, ""); // does not compile
}
```

Therefore, you have to use the `operator""_(char const *, std::size_t)`-literal operator:

```
constexpr std::uint32_t operator""_crc(char const * str, std::size_t len)
{
  char const * end = str + len;
  std::uint32_t hash = uCRCTable[0];
  for (; str < end; ++str)
  {
    hash = uCRCTable[(hash ^ *str) & 0xff] ^ hash >> 8;
  }
  return ~hash;
}
```

Since c++14 loops are allowed in constexpr-functions so these kind of string-literal operators are usable at compile time.

Comment: Unfortunately, it must be handled by a template parameter. It cannot be using the normal argument list

Comment: Why? This overload of `operator""` does work in `constexpr`-contexts.

Comment: But it generates other code which is a problem for me.

Comment: *"is easier to handle"*. It is in fact the only standard way.

Comment: Right, I always forget that the `<char...>`-Version only applies to numbers and not to strings.

Comment: There's no such type as `uint_32t`. It should be `uint32_t`.

Comment: @nowi "*But it generates other code which is a problem for me*" - you are going to have to be more specific about your troubles if you want to get help to solve it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry, to clarify: i need it to return a different type depending on the parameters. this returns a crc32 of the string for a class parameter

Comment: Right now it is simply not possible to return a type of a string-literal-operator that depends on the content of the string. This is only possible for the `<char...>`-overload but unfortunately this one is not usable according to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues.

There are no template version for string. gcc has **extension** for that

```
template<typename Char, Char... str >
constexpr uint32_t operator "" _crc()
```

So you need to use other overload

`constexpr std::uint_32t operator""_crc(char const * str, std::size_t len)`

Second issue if you miss the `else` part of `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename Char, Char... str >
constexpr uint32_t operator "" _crc( )
{
    constexpr auto lambda = [ ]( auto l,
                                 uint32_t crc,
                                 auto first,
                                 auto ... lstr )
    {
        if constexpr ( sizeof...( lstr ) == 0 )
            return ~crc;
        else
            return l( l,
                  uCRCTable[ ( crc ^ first ) & 0xFF ] ^ crc >> 8,
                  lstr... );
    };
    return lambda( lambda,
                   uCRCTable[ 0 ],
                   str... );
}
```

else you recursive function is still instantiated, even when `sizeof...( lstr ) == 0`.

But with `constexpr std::uint_32t operator""_crc(char const * str, std::size_t len)` overload, you won't have `if constexpr` issue anyway

Comment: Hm, didn't solve it. The issue seems to be somehow that MSVC is saying that string user literal operators must have an argument list and it cant be done through template parameters. Weird

Comment: Found main issue, there are no template UDL version for string (yet) :(.

Comment: Is there a similar extension for MSVC?

Comment: @nowi: Not from my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

What about C++20 ?

In [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) i read that, starting from C++20,

> If the overload set includes a string literal operator template with a non-type template parameter for which `str` is a well-formed template argument, then the user-defined literal expression is treated as a function call `operator "" X<str>()`,

So I suppose that if the string argument can be used to construct a `str` object for a template value parameter...

I imagine something as follows

```
#include <cstdint>

struct Crc
 {
   std::uint32_t  val;

   static constexpr std::uint32_t getCrc (char const * str)
    { return 123u; }

   constexpr Crc (char const * str) : val{getCrc(str)}
    { }
 };

template <Crc crcVal>
constexpr std::uint32_t operator "" _crc ()
 { return crcVal.val; }

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( 123u == "hello world"_crc );
 }
```

Obviously you have to modify `getCrc()` to compute an effective CRC.

Unfortunately this, at the  moment, seems to works with g++ but not with clang++.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment...

> @RemyLebeau sorry, to clarify: i need it to return a different type depending on the parameters. this returns a crc32 of the string for a class parameter

As noted in that comment thread, there is no way to do that in a standard compliant way (through the C++17).

If you can use either clang or gcc, then you can use the gcc extension as both support it.  I often forget about MSVC unless it is explicitly mentioned - I've not really used a windows-based OS since they went from Windows 3 to Windows ME.

However, since your crc function is constexpr, you can map the crc value to a unique type.

```cpp
constexpr std::uint32_t
operator""_crc(char const * str, std::size_t len)
{
    // implementation to compute the value
}

template <auto Val>
struct CRC
: std::integral_constant<decltype(Val), Val>
{ };

// example...
constexpr auto zzz = CRC<"zzz"_crc>{};
```

You will get a unique type for each unique value returned from "some string"_crc.

It's not as nice, but you may not get much closer to what you want with string literals using your compiler.

Before you commit to using a 32-bit CRC, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210298/probability-of-collision-when-using-a-32-bit-hash) to see the chance of getting a collision (e.g., producing the same hash with different strings) and make sure you are comfortable with it.