# Alternating Template Parameters Pack

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

How do I achieve a pack of alternating template parameters?

Something like this:

```
template< ( unsigned non_type, typename type )... >
```

Where the usage must be

```
my_class< 5U, float,
          6U, std::string >
```

I don't want to change the order nor do I want to have a wrapper around it as a pair during usage. Obviously, if it devolves into some sort of a pair in my own internal implementation, that's fine.

Comment: You can't. Why is this a requirement?

Comment: @Brian I'm making a tuple map

Comment: If you're making a map from non-types to types, shouldn't a wrapper syntax make more sense? Like `my_class<Entry<5, float>, Entry<'A', std::string>, ...>`

Comment: It might in certain cases but not mine. In mine, it would serve only to bloat the code.

Comment: No. This is a restriction of C++ variadic templates. There are some proposals, but none has made its way into C++17 or C++20 to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: You can write a recursive template that picks off two elements at a time.

Comment: @RaymondChen Please post a small example as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `template<unsigned key, typename Value, typename... Rest> struct my_class : my_class<Rest...> { /* ... */ };` and define a base case.

Comment: @RaymondChen this would not allow more than 1 pair of unsigned and typename

Comment: Oops, you're right. A pack must be all-types or all-values (of the same type). Can you type-ify the integers? Like `template<unsigned v> struct index { static constexpr unsigned value = v;}; template<typename Index, typename Type, typename...Rest> struct my_class :my_class<Rest...> { /* Index::value */ }; my_struct<index<5>, float, index<6>, std::string>`

Comment: @RaymondChen to do that, I'd solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985011/compile-time-only-crc32-user-literal

Answer (score 2):

The thing to remember about templates is that they're *not macros*. They are not copying tokens around. They're actual C++ constructs. Every template parameter must be of a specific kind: a type parameter, a non-type parameter, or a template-template parameter which must have its template parameter list specified. The kind of a template parameter lets the compiler know whether the use of that parameter in a particular place makes sense.

For example, this is potentially meaningful code:

```
template<auto value>
auto foo() {return value + 1;}
```

This is obviously nonsense:

```
template<typename value>
auto foo() {return value + 1;}
```

The compiler doesn't even have to wait for you to instantiate the template to shut you down.

The only way to use a parameter pack is to expand it in some location. And expanding a parameter pack applies the pattern which uses the pack to *all* elements of the pack. It's very difficult to construct a scenario where types and values could both fit into the syntax of the pattern.

It isn't impossible to do so, of course. For example, `(pack(something), ...)` could be legitimate for both type and non-type template parameters. But they won't be doing the same thing. For values, it will be invoking any available `operator()` on the type; for types, it will be calling a constructor to create a prvalue.

The most generically useful case would be to expand a heterogeneous pack directly into a template argument list.

However, all of this is sophistry, because C++ templates aren't macros. Template parameters must be of a well-defined kind so that the compiler can know if they are being used properly. And this includes parameter packs. So all elements of a pack must be of the same kind. What you want would be called "[universal template parameters](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1985r0.pdf)", but those are only a proposal at present.

Comment: Then how can I accomplish this with macros? Is there a way to split the `__VA_ARGS__` and alternate through each?

Comment: @nowi: My point is that the problem isn't with alternating through them. It's that they're not all of the same *kind*. Processing through pairs of a pack is just as easy as processing through single elements; it's just recursion, where you pull off two "head" elements instead of one. The problem is that you can't have NTTPs and type parameters in the same pack. Macros may have the reverse problem, where iterating by pairs is hard but a parameter could store anything. I've never done macro metaprogramming of that sort.

Comment: I understand. So I won't use a template pack and instead will use a macro where the macro just fills in the members of the template using a template structure that is defined like `template< auto first, typename second >struct`. `#define make_my_class( ... ) my_class< my_pair< __VA_ARGS__[0], __VA_ARGS__[1] >... >` But obviously as something that would work since `__VA_ARGS__` doesn't function like that.