# Is CRC32 suitable for this operation?

Tags: php, crc32

If I want to generate a checksum, for some product attributes concatanated with a custom string, and use this checksum later on, to see if any attribute in the same product changed over time, is php's `crc32` method suitable?

For example, let's say I have a product with the following attributes:

> color: red
> size: xl

I am trying to get the checksum for this product by creating the following string: `red||xl` and then running the `crc32` function on this string. If later on, the size is identified differently, or the product gets a new attribute, I want to identify this difference by the changing of the checksum on this product.

The baseline is, am I safe in using the `crc32` method for this, or I should opt for a slower but more secure hashing algorithm, with less collission?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of collision when using a 32 bit hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210298/probability-of-collision-when-using-a-32-bit-hash)

Comment: Short version: it depends how many inputs you're going to have. But the difference in computational effort between crc32 and a more complex hashing function (even md5 would provide a huge amount of benefit, for a non-secure application) is probably negligble. Something with a 128-bit output is going to be *drastically* more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Define "suitable".

I see little reason to *not* use a cryptographic hash here. If you have a) millions of strings, or b) malicious users who would like to trick you into thinking the attributes are the same, you should use a cryptographic hash. SHA-256 should be readily available. Feel free to use only 128 bits of it if you need to save the space. You'll still have a negligible probability of collision.

*Update:*

Based on the comments, a cryptographic hash would not be of benefit. I would recommend [XXH128](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash) as an extremely fast hash that would effectively eliminate the possibility of collision.

Comment: I am not worried about the space (but indeed that could also cause a problem), I am trying to save time. At the moment, I am talking about potentially hashing ~3 million products, 12 times a day, and while this is still not so big of a time, considering all the other things that should run on the server, and the possiblity of later on having 10 or 100 times the number of items in the database, I am trying to opt for the fastest hashing algorithm, that still suits my needs. Users won't be able to input data here, only administrators, so tricking the system is not a problem imo.