# What is probability of collision in CRC32 in first 4.2Billion

Tags: collision-detection, crc32

I am using numbers as input and length will be 10 characters.

EG.
Input - 8429294732
Output - 96325be7

Total possibility of crc32 is 16^8 which is roughly 4.2Billion.

Does anyone know what is chance of collision here?

And can you please explain.

Comment: How can a 32 bits data store 16^8 distinct values ?

Comment: First 4.2 billion what?  The first 4.2 billion random 10 character strings?  There is almost 100% probability of at least one collision.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217471/1180620).

Assuming you mean ten decimal digits of uniform, independent probability, then your inputs will result in on the order of 90% coverage of the possible 32-bit CRC values. We will use the formula with *n* = 0.9 2<sup>32</sup>, and from the question title I will presume, *k* = 2<sup>32</sup>. You will have about two billion collisions. If the inputs are chosen randomly, the chance of *not* having a collision is about 10<sup>-1036266998</sup>. Also known in practical terms as: zero.

(By the way, your "roughly 4.2 billion", should be roughly 4.3 billion.)

Comment: can you please elaborate about your assertion “90% coverage of the possible 32-bit CRC values”? The source has 10^10 possible symbols and the CRC, 4.3x10^9. Thanks!

Comment: If you randomly throw 10^10 darts at a dart board with 2^32 spots (and they all hit the dart board), then about 90% of the spots will have been hit by a dart.

Comment: On average, 90.254%.

Comment: Ah! Pigeonhole principle! Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input uses the full range of the 10 digits, that would give you 10^10 different numbers, and you map this to 16^8=2^32 numbers generated by the CRC32. So, on average, you have (10^10)/(2^32)=2.3 numbers mapped to every possible CRC32 value generated.
So, the answer to your question is that you have 100% chance of collision.